# How to find the equation of a parabola with vertex on the line y = -3x?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Its axis are parallel to the y-axis and passing through (-7,13) and (5,1).

Comment: So you know that the coordinates of the vertex are $ \ (X \ , \ -3X) \ . $  Since the parabola has a "vertical" symmetry axis, its "standard form" equation is $ \ 4p \ y  \ = \ (x - X)^2 \ . $  You have two unknowns, $ \ X \ $ and $ \ p \ $ , and you know two points that the curve passes through.  So there is sufficient information to solve for those unknowns.

Comment: So you're saying is that I'll just the given points to those equations and afterwards, I'll eventually get the equation I need?

Comment: You use the equation for the parabola, which should be $$  4p \ (y - [-3X] ) \ = \ (x - X)^2 \ \ , $$ with each of the given points, which gives you two equations with numbers in them.  This will let you solve for both $ \ X \ $ and $ \ p \ $ simultaneously.  You will then be able to use those values to produce the equation you seek for the parabola.  (And my apologies for mis-writing the equation in my first comment.)

Comment: No problem and thnx very much. Saved me from getting low grades if ever all my answers would be right :)

Comment: I think you will find that there are two distinct parabolas that satisfy the conditions of the problem.

Comment: Yes, there are.  I'm making a graph as we type...

Comment: Great. I made one too but don't know how to include such things.

Comment: Above the "answer box", you will see among the icons what looks like a little picture in a frame: that is the "button" for the tool to upload images.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner thanks for the tip! Fairly new to SE.

Answer (score 1):

With the vertex given as $ \ (X \ , \ -3X) \ , $ and the information that the symmetry axis of the parabola is "vertical" (parallel to the $ \ y-$ axis), we can write the standard-form equation of the parabola as

$$ 4p \ (y + 3X) \ = \ (x - X)^2 \ \ .  $$

For the points we are told lie on this curve, we obtain two simultaneous equations,

$$ 4p \ (13 + 3X) \ = \ (-7 - X)^2 \ \ \text{and} \ \ 4p \ (1 + 3X) \ = \ (5 - X)^2 \ \ .  $$

This looks a bit messier than it actually is, since some terms cancel when we subtract one equation from the other.  We will get a simple relation between $ \ p \ $ and $ \ X \ $ which we can then substitute into either of these equations to find $ \ X \ $ , and thus the coordinates of the vertex and the value of $ \ p \ $ .

There are, in fact, two solutions for $ \ X \ $ and, correspondingly, two parabolas through the specified points with their vertices on $ \ y = -3x \ $ .  The graph below presents the situation.

[image]

*The two parabolas intersect at the points $ \ (-7,13) \ \ $ and $ \ (5,1) \ $ , as required.  The red line is $ \ y = -3x \ , $ on which the vertices of both parabolas lie.*